# Proving that the left regular representation is a product of $m$ $n$-cycles in the symmetric group of degree $mn$ where $m$ and $n$ are coprime?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group and $π : G → S_{|G|}$ the left regular representation. Assume that
$|G| = mn$ with $m$ and $n$ co-prime. Suppose that $x \in G$ has order $n$, show that $π(x)$ is a
product of $m$ $n$-cycles in $S_{mn}$.

This question is killing me, I can see that it is true based on another problem I did that asked for the computation of the image, but I have no idea why that is the case. I know as a "clue" that a few students found solutions where the coprime part of the question is unnecessary but I still don't know WHY there are $m$ $n$-cycles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint 1:

> Clearly all cycles of $\pi(x)$ have length at most $n$ (since $x^n=1$). Suppose a cycle in $\pi(x)$ has length $k<n$.

Hint 2 (this is a big hint):

> For an element $a$ appearing in this cycle, $x^ka=\pi(x^k)(a)=a$.

Finished solution:

> Multiplying on the right by $a^{-1}$ we obtain $x^k=1$ contrary to the assumption that $n>k$ is the order of $x$.

Comment: Could you please explain the first hint? I apologize but I have been struggling with this group theory stuff lately so my intuitive understanding isn't very good.

Comment: That's ok! $\pi(x)$ can't have a cycle length $>n$ otherwise $\pi(x^n)=\pi(x)^n\ne 1$. If a cycle $\sigma$ appearing in $\pi(x)$ has length $k<n$ then $\sigma^k$ is trivial, so $\pi(x)^k$ acts trivially on anything that appears in $\sigma$ hence the second hint.

Comment: Ok I see now thank you

Answer (score 1):

It is true that you do not need the fact that gcd$(m,n)=1$. If $x \in G$ has order $n$, than the left regular presentation gives rise to an element of $S_{|G|}$ with $\frac{|G|}{n}$ cycles of length $n$. When I taught this to my students I wrote out a small example, I suggest you do the same: taken for example $V_4 \hookrightarrow$ $S_4$, or $S_3 \hookrightarrow S_6$ and see what happens. See also the answer of Robert Chamberlain.

Comment: The previous problem I did was the symmetric group of degree 3 mapped in the symmetric group of degree 6 and so that's when I realized that this was true. I just am not sure why

A) Why the cycles must all be the same length (n) as X
and 
B) For what reason there are |G|/n cycles of that length

Comment: Well, let me explain it with group actions. View it as $G$ acting on itself: the length of the cycle induced by an element $x$ of order $n$ is the same as the length of the orbit. Here you can view $\langle x \rangle$ as acting on $G$. Obviously, the stabilizer of a $g \in G$ equals $\{1\}$. Hence the orbit of $g$ has length $|\langle x \rangle : \{1\}|=n$. And this reasoning holds for any $g$ and any $x$.